# Save image issue after converting 2d to 3d array

Tags: python, arrays, image, types, save

I have convert 2d array(arr2d) to 3d array(arr3d) and save as image using below code. arr2d is float64 type. Why save image is not color image?

```
arr3d[:, :, 0] = arr3d[:, :, 1] = arr3d[:, :, 2] = arr2d
arr3d=arr3d*255
im=Image.fromarray(np.maximum(np.minimum(arr3d, 255), 0).astype(np.uint8))
im.save(“sample.png”)
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The image is not color image because for every pixel red green and blue color channels have the same value.

When using `im=Image.fromarray(arr3d)`:

- `arr3d[:, :, 0]` is the red pixels plane.
- `arr3d[:, :, 1]` is the green pixels plane.
- `arr3d[:, :, 2]` is the blue pixels plane.

When using `arr3d[:, :, 0] = arr3d[:, :, 1] = arr3d[:, :, 2] = arr2d` you are making sure that **red=green=blue** for every pixel.

The color of pixel with R=G=B is **gray**.

I created the following code for reproducing the issue:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

arr2d = np.random.rand(50, 50) # Create 50x50 2D array with random values in range [0, 1]
arr3d = np.zeros((50, 50, 3))
arr3d[:, :, 0] = arr3d[:, :, 1] = arr3d[:, :, 2] = arr2d
arr3d = arr3d*255
im = Image.fromarray(np.maximum(np.minimum(arr3d, 255), 0).astype(np.uint8))
im.save("sample.png")
```

Result - all pixels are gray:
[image]

Example for getting result with some colors:

```
arr3d[:, :, 0] = np.random.rand(50, 50);arr3d[:, :, 1] = np.random.rand(50, 50);arr3d[:, :, 2] = np.random.rand(50, 50)
```

[image]